# How to add form controls to the existing form group - angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I have a form group which was build in ngOninit but later when one of that controls is clicked, I want to add few more controls to that existing form group based on the values got from another API in ngOninit. Below pictures shows the actual requirement. When I click on other role, I want to show other role controls which I've got from an API.[image]

since I'm new to angular2, can anyone help me to get out of this problem?

Comment: What are these *few more controls*, is a bit unclear. Should it be a new FormArray, new FormGroup or just "simple FormControls". It's really hard to help based on this information. You'd need to show some code what you have, what you want, what you have done to achieve what you want and where you have failed :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try with below approach.

```
 const arrayControl = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['formArray'];
        let newGroup = this.fb.group({
            /// new controls
        }
        arrayControl.push(newGroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method that controls and make validations on your form, if that is what you are asking.

Something like:

```
<button type="submit" (click)="save(f.value, f.valid)">Submit</button>
```

Where on your `save()` method you can validate the form and so on.

More information about form controls in Angular 2: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deal-with-different-form-controls-in-angular-2

**Update:**

As you are new to Angular 2, this have to be a **must read** for you:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html

It is very useful to understand how do dynamic forms behave in Angular2 and how to implement them.

**Update 2:**

I understood badly your question. If what you want is to add dynamically elements to your form the simplest approach would be to use `*ngIf` in order to show/hide elements dynamically.

Example:

```
<input type="text" *ngIf="showInput"/>
```

Documentation: [NgIf Directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html)

Comment: His question was to add controls to existing form group

Comment: @PramodPatil Oh! Thanks! I did not understand well the question. I have updated my answer! :D

Answer (score 0):

In FormGroup class their's a built in method : `addControl`

See more in angular documentation : https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addcontrol

Answer (score 0):

## In typescript Class (i.e component.ts)

```
// After Initializing the FormGroup 

this.FormGroup.addControl(
      'firstname',
      new FormControl('DefaultName', [Validators.required])
    );
```

## In HTML template (i.e component.html)

```html
<!-- Inside existing Form -->>

 <input type="text" formControlName="firstname" />
```